Library that lets you write tests in almost English like manner
I have a vague memory of a C# library being used some 10 years ago or so at a previous job. You would write almost English like sentences and it would pick up on key words and do something behind the scenes. So you would write like:
IF someVar equals to "1234", then (do something).

I believe it had a built in support for key words such as AND, OR, THEN, etc. Other things, like someVar in my example, custom to your needs would have to be coded manually. You would essentially code the C# middle layer between the English like file and the code that the operations were performed on. I believe it was used for testing purposes.
If it rings a bell for anyone, please share! I've search online for over an hour, but no luck.

Specflow is what I was looking for.
https://docs.specflow.org/projects/getting-started/en/latest/index.html

Would you mind adding more details, such as a sample test, to make this a quality answer? Thanks! :-)
